# Starting a Google Kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

1. We had a GKE cluster running a functional project
2. Then we sunseted the entire project -- by deleting it.
3. Due to a need, we restored the project
4. Now I'm trying to get the GKE cluster running again.

The first thing I tried was running `kubectl get pods` which returned `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp ***.***.***.***:443: i/o timeout` (I masked the ip with `*`)

Then I tried to open up the cloud shell in the browser, and noticed this message:

```
WARNING: cluster **** is not RUNNING. The kubernetes API may or may not be available. Check the cluster status for more information.
```

Ok, that explained why `kubectl` was not working. So how do I start the cluster then? That information I can't find anywhere.

Comment: I did rerun `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` as found in the Google Cloud

Answer (score 2):

Deleting a project [stops all the services](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects). [Restoring a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project) does not restart many services, including Google Kubernetes Engine.

Review that the project that you restored has [an active billing account linked](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/restart-services), and the easiest way to review the status of the GKE cluster is from the console. Go to the [Google Cloud Platform Console > COMPUTE > Kubernetes Engine > Clusters >  Select your cluster] section.

From there go to the NODES section, and there you can review the number of nodes for each nodepool. This number may be 0, so you may need [to resize it](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster)  to start the cluster.

Comment: Resizing the cluster did the trick --> it brought up an error message that our billing was not set up. That was the issue!